# Rural road/field dataset

Tags: data-request, images

Is there any open dataset, containing images or stereo-pairs of images of rural landscapes/roads/fields? Examples are attached. Any help appreciated.

Any location/time of day are suitable.

[image: rural road][image: rural road]

Comment: Does Google Street View not cover dirt/gravel roads? (I don't know the answer, just curious)

Comment: @BarryCarter Never seen anything like this on the GSV, none the less I haven't searched for such data there, thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I found something. But still if you find anything better, it would be great if you post it here.

**http://www.nrec.ri.cmu.edu/projects/usdapersondetection/dataset/**

> The NREC Person Detection Dataset is a collection of off-road videos taken in an apple orchard and orange grove. The videos are collected with a set of visible people in a variety of outfits, locations, and times. We encourage you to train a detector on our dataset and submit your curves for display on this webpage.
>
> Labels are provided in Pascal VOC format and images are provided as rectified pngs. A training set has been partitioned for algorithm training. A full validation set has been partitioned for algorithm tuning and development results. Finally, a test set is provided for final evaluation and publication. We ask that the test set be used only after completion of development, in order to preserve the integrity of the dataset.
>
> Scripts for working with the dataset can be found at: **https://github.com/zpezz/nrecAgPersonEval**
>
> The benchmark only requires the apples left labeled and oranges left labeled. The right images are provided for stereo. Additional left and right images, including 7 frames (1 second) before the labeled data begins are available in the unlabeled files. These can be used to compute motion features for detection or for visual odometry and new view synthesis benchmarking. Finally, the unassigned.zip file includes additional labeled data not included in the dataset, for instance, videos taken at night.

[image]

Comment: thanks for coming back to answer. If you don't actively need more answers, please mark this question as accepted.